# jQuery selector having trouble with & operator in kendo grid name

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using kendo gird in my mvc razor application for mutli level detail row expand feature. In order to have unique name for each grid I have some fixed text plus the unique Id of the row

e.g.

`@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModal>()
       .Name("topGrid_#=uniqueKeyColumnValue#")`

and on a row expand click, I know which detailed grid data I have to get by passing on this uniqueKeyColumnValue with its hard coded prefix. Things were fine so far but now I am told there are some special characters like as '&' operator in some of the values and when I construct the detail grid name by concatenating its prefix with uniqueKeyColumnValue

e.g.

```
    var idKey = e.sender.dataItem(e.masterRow).uniqueKeyColumnValue;

    var detailedGridName = '#detailedGrid' + idKey;
    var detailedGrid = $(detailedGridName).data("kendoGrid");
```

I am getting the following error

> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

at this row

> var detailedGrid = $(detailedGridName).data("kendoGrid");

that is obviously because of the & operator in idKey e.g. N&12345

I don't have the choice of giving a hard coded name to the grid. Any suggestion?

Comment: Better to use `_` or `-` instead of `&` to avoid escaping of special characters in selectors. See escaping rules: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I can't. Data is stored with these characters. even if i replace with _, it probably cause another challenge of reverting them back to retrieve the relevant key. Although, I can construct entirely a separate field and assigning the modified value by replace & with _ and use it for grid name and leaving the actual key column value as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this format `$("div[id='detailedGrid_" + idKey + "']").data('kendoGrid')`

Answer (score 0):

You need escape `&` with `\\`, better don't use it. `_`/`-` can serve the purpose.

```js
$('#N\\&12345').text('Yahoooooooooooooooo')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="N&12345"></div>
```

If you are using jQuery 3, then [jQuery.escapeSelector( selector )](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/) can be used.

```js
$('#' + jQuery.escapeSelector('N&12345')).text('Yahoooooooooooooooo')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="N&12345"></div>
```

Comment: How it would happen when I don't know the index position?

Comment: @LearningCurve, Which version of jQuery you are using?